# where is the log file locate for ibm mq on solaris

Tags: ibm-mq

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

Where is the IBM MQ logs locate on the solaris box MQ SERVER ?

[image]

Based on ibm documentation:
Based on ibm documentation online url there should be an errors folder.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=windows-error-log-directories

[image]

Comment: You are looking in /opt/mqm not in /var/mqm

Answer (score 1):

As JoshMc said, the queue manager related information is under /var/mqm/ directory.

i.e.

- ***/var/mqm/errors/*** directory has log files for general MQ issues and where you will find FDC files.
- ***/var/mqm/qmgrs/{QMgrName}/errors/*** directory contains the log files related to a particular queue manager.